# Reversing a string and preserving words in quotes

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to reverse words in a string but preserve the order for those in quotes. For example, let's say I have this string:

> hello and world or white fox

This is how I would generally go about achieving this:

```
string source = "hello and world or white fox";

string[] words = source.Split(' ');

words = words.Reverse().ToArray();

string newSource = string.Join(" ", words);
```

which would result in this:

> fox white or world and hello

Now let's say I change **source** to *'hello and world or "white fox"'*. Using this algorithm, the output is *'fox" "white or world and hello'*. Is there a way to preserve the order for *'white fox'* so that I would get something like *'"white fox" or world and hello'*?

Comment: what if the input is `hello and "world or "white fox"`? or `hello and "world or" white fox"`...?

Comment: This is part of a lexical analyzer. There are already conditions (including odd number of "s, space between AND and OR and the token, etc.) which would throw an exception if met. It is however, possible that `"white fox"` is in the middle of the string.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Do you genuinely need the solution to use a regular expression, or is an answer that does not involve regular expressions acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
string newSource = String.Join(" ", 
    Regex.Matches(source, @"\w+|""[\w\s]+""").Cast<Match>().Reverse());
```

This will find any single 'words' composed of letters, digits, or underscores, or composites of words and white space characters surrounded by quotes, then reverses the matches and joins the results.

The result will be something like this:

- `"hello and world or white fox"` => `"fox white or world and hello"`.
- `"hello and world or \"white fox\""` => `"\"white fox\" or world and hello"`.

Unfortunately, this will completely ignore any non-word characters (e.g. `"foo - bar"` => `"bar foo"`), but the pattern can be modified to take other characters into account.

<sup>**NOTE:** See MSDN [Word Character: \w](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter) for the precise definition of a word character.</sup>

Comment: Nice. What does the `|` imply in the pattern?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange It's an *alternation*. `A|B` means roughly 'match either pattern `A` or pattern `B`'.

Answer (score 1):

this pattern will only match spaces outside quotes `(\s)(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"[^"]*){2})*$)|\s(?!.*")`
[demo](http://regex101.com/r/sC1zY8)

Comment: sounds interesting, just tested with `hello and "world or" white fox"`, it even doesn't match the **2 first spaces**.

Comment: your test sentence has an odd number of quotes which is not a valid sentence with quoted text. this pattern will look for spaces followed by even number of quotes or none

Comment: but it's a **possible** input, in fact we have to choose between the match `"world or"` or `" white fox"` but it depends on the rule we need to adopt.

Comment: I see your point, and I don't know how to match a space outside quotes in that situation :-(